# How do I run other windows forms while enabling a reference? Once I connect my reference, the application gets stuck on only one form

Tags: c#, winforms, reference

[visual studio problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRcjI.png)
I am trying to run different windows forms but once I enable my reference to TrackerLibrary, my Application.Run gets stuck on only being able to run the last form it was on before enabling my reference. Is there some way to fix this? (new to coding so I don't know if I'm missing anything)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Application.Run method is what starts your application and the program will not go past that method call unless the user exits the application.

Using `Application.Run(Form mainForm)` will only allow you to start your application with 1 open form and the application will exit when that form is closed.

If you'd like to open more than 1 Form on start, consider using `Application.Run(ApplicationContext context)`.
[Application.Run Method documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.run)

Comment: My mistake, I might have said this weirdly. This is what I mean: Whenever I run the CreatePrizeForm first with my reference disabled, it runs fine and pops up the correct form. But then when I enable my reference and run the CreateTeamForm (again, with the CreatePrizeForm code commented out) it still makes the CreatePrizeForm even though no code is telling it to run. Enabling my reference seems to make it stuck on a single form.

Comment: I can't think of how the reference to TrackerLibrary could affect this behavior, since Program.cs isn't even using it. Did you copy paste the CreatePrizeForm to create CreateTeamForm? Maybe the forms just look identical?

Comment: I created new forms for each form and copy+pasted elements within the form, the different forms themselves have separate names and designs and it works whenever I call each of the different forms to be ran, but for some reason once I enable that reference it just breaks.

Comment: Actually looking at your screenshot, I can see you have compile errors, but your program is running. You probably got the `There were build errors. Would you like to continue and run the last successful build?` dialog and clicked Yes. So it ran the build that still had the `Application.Run(new CreatePrizeForm());` uncommented. You need to fix the compile errors before trying to run your program.

Comment: Actually, that seems like that might be it, thank you, let me get on it.

Answer (score 0):

Your application doesn't get "stuck on one form". You can open as many other forms as you want. What you can't do is close that first form without the application exiting. When you call `Application.Run` and pass a form, that method will return if and only if that form closes, at which point your `Main` method will also complete, if you have no more code after the `Application.Run` call.

If you want to be able to close a form without the application exiting then you cannot pass that form to `Application.Run`. What you can do instead is derive your own class from [`ApplicationContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.applicationcontext) and then create an instance of that class and pass it to `Application.Run` instead. You can then put whatever logic you want in that class to open and close as many forms as you like.

I'm not going to provide any code here because I don't know specifically what it is you want to do. Better that you follow the link above and work through the example it provides in order to understand the concept, then implement it as you need. You might also like to check out my own example of using a custom `ApplicationContext` [here](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?637483).